# Something like convertConstraintsToView:?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to animate my `view` (which is wherever in views hierarchy) to become fullscreen. 
For this I'm adding `view` to `UIWindow` instance.

*p.s. I'm using masonry*

```
// replacing superview
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self];

// fullscreen constraints
[self remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.superview);
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration
                 animations:^{
                     [self layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Problem I have here is that when view is added to window it doesnt keep same position as it was before which is, I assume, correct behaviour but looks weird.

Animation starts from wrong place.

it's not difficult to achive using frames by doing:

- convert rect of view to window (`convertRect:toView:`)
- move view to window (so view keeps same position)
- animate view's frame to be fullscreen

How I can achive this with `autolayout`? 
(or I still have to use frames?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have the cause and solution to your problem. If you didn't change superview then it wouldn't be an issue.

Get and convert the frame as you describe, but don't set the frame. Use the frame to set the initial constraints. This will keep the view in the original position even though it's moved to a new superview (and hence coordinate system).

Now animate the setting of the constants of those constraints to zero. This will draw the edges of the view out to meet the superview edges.

Comment: that's what I also thought, seems like no other ways

Comment: there are other ways, like you pass the full screen view an image of the original view and the frame and have it animate the image, there are many options...

Comment: well... I mean no normal ones :)